# Spring Boot: GraalVM Native Image Support

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, graalvm

I have a Spring Boot project which was initially using version 2.7.6 with Java 11 and currently, I am adding the [GraalVM Native Image Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html) by following the documentation with [Building a Native Image Using Buildpacks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.developing-your-first-application.buildpacks) option. I have changed the version to 3.1.0 with Java 17 and modified the pom.xml. I have also done the changes regarding spring-data-jpa and refactored the import statements and now I am able to run the application.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</parent>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

My understanding of adding the GraalVM is that it will make the application start-up time faster and reduce the build size of jar file or the docker image of an application. Below is the comparison.

**Before GraalVM:**  
Application start in ~7s 
Time to run `mvn clean install` ~15s  
Jar file size ~61MB

**After GraalVM:**  
Application start in : ~2s  
Time to run `mvn clean install -Pnative` ~12s  
Jar file size ~77MB

**Questions are:**

1. I can see the performance on the application startup time which is good, however jar file size has increased which is supposed to be less than ~61MB
2. Does I am using the correct command for build with GraalVM by using `mvn clean install -Pnative`
3. In the documentation there is note as below, do I need to add anything in the pom.xml?

> The builder used for the images is paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny. It
> has small footprint and reduced attack surface, but you can also use
> paketobuildpacks/builder:base or paketobuildpacks/builder:full to have
> more tools available in the image if required.

If I do add below in the configurations of spring-boot-maven-plugin, I am getting the shared error message

```
                <image>
                    <buildpacks>
                        <buildpack>paketobuildpacks/builder:full</buildpack>
                    </buildpacks>
                    <env>
                        <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                    </env>
                </image>
```

**class org.springframework.boot.maven.Image cannot be cast to class org.springframework.boot.maven.FilterableDependency (org.springframework.boot.maven.Image and org.springframework.boot.maven.FilterableDependency are in unnamed module of loader org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm @6228d0bd)**

---

**UPDATE:**

When I do run `mvn -Pnative native:compile` I am getting the below error.

**Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory was unintentionally initialized at build time. To see why org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService was unintentionally initialized at build time. To see why org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService**

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>abc</name>
    <description>Application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <springdoc-openapi-ui.version>1.6.13</springdoc-openapi-ui.version>
        <problem.version>0.26.0</problem.version>
        <org.json.version>20220320</org.json.version>
        <apache.commons.lang3.version>3.12.0</apache.commons.lang3.version>
        <checkstyle-plugin.version>3.2.0</checkstyle-plugin.version>
        <checkstyle.version>10.5.0</checkstyle.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${org.json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons.lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${problem.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-problem</artifactId>
            <version>${problem.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.xeroapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>xero-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.26.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.43.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <buildpacks>
                            <buildpack>paketobuildpacks/builder:full</buildpack>
                        </buildpacks>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.26</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>checkstyle</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <excludes>**/module-info.java,**/target/**/*,**/protocols/**/*</excludes>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In console I can also see the below logs

```
Warning: Could not resolve org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.
Warning: Could not resolve com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.
Warning: Could not resolve groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.
Warning: Could not resolve groovy.lang.Script for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.Script.
Warning: Could not resolve groovy.lang.Script for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.Script.
Warning: Could not resolve groovyjarjarantlr.CommonToken for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovyjarjarantlr.CommonToken.
Warning: Could not resolve javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue.
Warning: Could not resolve javax.money.MonetaryAmount for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.money.MonetaryAmount.
Warning: Could not resolve org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.GroovySourceAST for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.GroovySourceAST.
Warning: Could not resolve org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation.
Warning: Could not resolve org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.
Warning: Could not resolve org.glassfish.expressly.ValueExpressionImpl for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.expressly.ValueExpressionImpl.
Warning: Could not resolve org.glassfish.expressly.parser.AstValue for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.expressly.parser.AstValue.
Warning: Could not resolve org.joda.time.ReadableInstant for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant.
Warning: Could not register method org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.time.future.FutureValidatorForReadablePartial.<init>() for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.
Warning: Could not register method org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.time.futureorpresent.FutureOrPresentValidatorForReadablePartial.<init>() for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.
Warning: Could not register method org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.time.past.PastValidatorForReadablePartial.<init>() for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.
Warning: Could not register method org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.time.pastorpresent.PastOrPresentValidatorForReadablePartial.<init>() for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.getScheduledExecutorService() not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.isInitializationFailFast() not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.isJdbc4ConnectionTest() not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setInitializationFailFast(boolean) not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setJdbc4ConnectionTest(boolean) not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setScheduledExecutorService(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) not found.
Warning: Could not resolve oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.
Warning: Could not resolve org.h2.Driver for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver.
Warning: Could not resolve org.postgresql.util.PGobject for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.getScheduledExecutorService() not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.isInitializationFailFast() not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.isJdbc4ConnectionTest() not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setInitializationFailFast(boolean) not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setJdbc4ConnectionTest(boolean) not found.
Warning: Method com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setScheduledExecutorService(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) not found.
Warning: Could not resolve org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform.
Warning: Could not resolve oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.
Warning: Could not resolve org.h2.Driver for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver.
Warning: Could not resolve org.postgresql.util.PGobject for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject.
Warning: Could not resolve org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.
Warning: Could not resolve com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.
Warning: Could not resolve groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.
Warning: Could not resolve groovy.lang.Script for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.Script.
Warning: Could not resolve groovy.lang.Script for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.Script.
Warning: Could not resolve groovyjarjarantlr.CommonToken for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovyjarjarantlr.CommonToken.
Warning: Could not resolve javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue.
Warning: Could not resolve javax.money.MonetaryAmount for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.money.MonetaryAmount.
Warning: Could not resolve org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.GroovySourceAST for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.GroovySourceAST.
Warning: Could not resolve org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation.
Warning: Could not resolve org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.
Warning: Could not resolve org.glassfish.expressly.ValueExpressionImpl for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.expressly.ValueExpressionImpl.
Warning: Could not resolve org.glassfish.expressly.parser.AstValue for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.expressly.parser.AstValue.
Warning: Could not resolve org.joda.time.ReadableInstant for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant.
Warning: Could not register method org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.time.future.FutureValidatorForReadablePartial.<init>() for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.
Warning: Could not register method org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.time.futureorpresent.FutureOrPresentValidatorForReadablePartial.<init>() for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.
Warning: Could not register method org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.time.past.PastValidatorForReadablePartial.<init>() for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.
Warning: Could not register method org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.time.pastorpresent.PastOrPresentValidatorForReadablePartial.<init>() for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.
```

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same problem of your update and I fixed it by adding this args configuration in native-maven-plugin.

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
      <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <buildArgs>
          <arg>
             --initialize-at-build-time=org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory,org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService,
          </arg>
        </buildArgs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can see the performance on the application startup time which is good, however jar file size has increased which is supposed to be less than ~61MB

A native image is a platform-specific binary that can be executed without a JVM. The size of the jar file isn't relevant.

> Does I am using the correct command for build with GraalVM by using mvn clean install -Pnative

If you want to use buildpacks to create a container image that contains a native executable you should run `mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image`.

If you want to build a native executable directly on your machine, you should run `mvn -Pnative native:compile`. You also need to add the Native Build Tools Maven plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

> If I do add below in the configurations of spring-boot-maven-plugin, I am getting the shared error message

It's hard to tell with only a snippet of configuration and no stack trace but I suspect you've placed the configuration within the wrong tags. It should look something like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <image>
            <buildpacks>
                <buildpack>paketobuildpacks/builder:full</buildpack>
            </buildpacks>
            <env>
                <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
            </env>
        </image>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, I have updated the details in the question, can you please help with that?

Comment: Can I create the container image uisng the jib with `mvn compile -Pnative jib:build -Dimage=$REPO:$TAG -Djib.container.environment=SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod` Do I will need to use paketobuildpacks if I use jib?

Comment: Your edits have completely changed the question. Please ask a new question instead of doing that.

Buildpacks and Jib are two separate ways of building container images. You should use one or the other.

Comment: Yes Andy, Can I use jib with GraalVM native using `mvn compile -Pnative jib:build -Dimage=$REPO:$TAG -Djib.container.environment=SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod` without adding the buildpacks?

Comment: Adding the bulidpacks will have no effect on how jib behaves. Whether jib can build a container image for a native image is another separate question. You probably want to look at https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions/tree/9583ac44e3b7097d191696f40714d40526ab85ff/first-party/jib-native-image-extension-maven.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the command :

```
mvn -Pnative clean install
```

Add below in pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>native</id>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.25</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-image</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```